# Get back to above rule in clips

Tags: clips, expert-system

when I try to call a `defrule` that have been used already, clips stop..

some `defrule` need to be used more than one time, is there any way to do it

here is an example

```
(

defrule choice-in-powerPlant2
(powerPlant2-question)
=>
(printout t "Are Filter and Carburetor Air working fine(y/n)?" crlf)
(bind ?response (check-YNoptions-input)); Get user input on type of questions
(if (eq ?response y)
    then
    (assert (powerPlant1-question)
    )
)

(if (or(eq ?response q) (eq ?response Q))
    then 
(output-exitmessage)

)

(if (eq ?response n)
    then
        (printout t "Have you fixed this(y/n)?" crlf)
        (bind ?response (check-YNoptions-input)); Get user input on type of questions
        (if (eq ?response y)
            then
            (assert (powerPlant1-question)
            )
        )
        (if (eq ?response n)
            then
            (printout req "Please replace Filter and Carburetor Air " crlf)
            (assert (powerPlant3-question))
    )
)
)
```

in rule 2
I want to go back to rule 1 when I enter "y"=yes

" running stopped once I enterd "y" "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrigger a rule that matches a specific fact, retract that fact as part of the rule action. If another rule then asserts that specific fact, the rule will be retriggered. For example:

```
(defrule choice-in-powerPlant2
   ?f <- (powerPlant2-question)
   =>
   (retract ?f)
   (printout t "Are Filter and Carburetor Air working fine(y/n)?" crlf)
      .
      .
      .
)
```

Comment: It is work now !!
thank u sooooooooooooooooo much ^____^
thank u Gary ^____________^

Comment: I just wanna know if this could work for all defrule with only write it once ?
or i have to write that  code for each rule ?

Comment: You'd have to do it for each rule that you want to execute repeatedly.

Comment: Mr.Gray, I have another problem, when I enter "no", I want that show "meassage", then directly go to another rule.................................. (if (eq ?response n)
 then
  
    
   (printout t "Please  register level1 and go to case 6" crlf)
   (assert (case46))
  )

Comment: Post your code so the behavior you're describing can be reproduced.